# Lua Timer(s) on command

Tags: timer, lua

Sorry, but this one is what some may call an open-ended question.

I am attempting to make a command where if someone says !spectate, they are put in spectate mode, and stay in there for 30 seconds. So far I have been totally unsuccessful, and as such, have no idea really of what I'm doing, so not erroneous code available :(

Here's some things which may assist those who answer:

To put one in spectate mode, after someone says !spectate (without the 30 second limit) you do this:

```
if Message == "!spectate" then
  InputConsole("spectate %d", pID)
end
```

The game this will be used with is Command and Conquer: Renegade

Sorry I can't be much more helpful than that, I am totally out of my depth here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

However you'd go about doing this would be specific to Renegade's Lua API.  I've never used it myself, but the almighty Google reckons that Renegades uses [LuaTT](http://luaplugin.wikispaces.com/functions), for which the API docs say:

> You can have only 255 scripts attached to objects. For timers, make your own api based of OnThink and os.time

The docs aren't particularly good, but a quick look at the example code found [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/29623549/LuaTT_091011.rar) suggests something along these lines would work:

```
local timers = {
  { time = 1343910384, cb = function() doSomething() end }
}

function OnThink()  -- this is called every frame
  for i = 1, #timers do
    if os.time() > timers[i].time then 
      timers[i].cb()
      table.remove(timers, i)
    end
  end
end
```

The code you posted would then look something like this:

```
if Message == "!spectate" then
  InputConsole("spectate %d", pID) -- move player to spectators
  table.insert(timers, {
    time = os.time() + 30,                                 -- 30 seconds from now,
    cb   = function() InputConsole("spectate %d", pID) end -- remove player from spectators
  })
end
```

Comment: furq, you come to my aid again and again! You truely are a legend :P

Comment: Hm, something wasn't quite right with it though ;o Also, did you miss the closing parenthesis off (timers, ? In any case, it turns me into spectate, but does not pull me out of it later.

Comment: Can you put a print() or something in the callback to make sure it's definitely being fired?

Comment: The callback is the function you're putting into `timers`; `cb = function() InputConsole("spectate %d", pID); Console_Output("callback fired") end`.

Comment: Ah I see... Well, nothing appeared in the console (I assume you expected "callback fired" to) and it still has not brought me out of it.

Comment: Bleeh, I've still had no luck :( I've tried tweaking it and then seeing but in the end I had no different result from what I have already explained. It appears that the timer isn't actually being activated...

Comment: Does Console_Output() work elsewhere?  Does it do anything if you call it from within onThink()?  The docs for this are really bad and some bits of it seem to be from a separate mod, so it's hard to debug it without installing Renegade myself.

Comment: I am unsure whether it will, I will try a InputConsole("msg Test works") rather than a Console_Output... as for working in OnThink, commands must be given in OnChat as that is the function which detects words spoken in the ingame chat.

Comment: I can now confirm that it does not get called. In OnThink the spectate command is not even recognised.

Comment: Argh, it looks like it's `OnThink()` (capital O)... does that make any difference? :(

Comment: holyshiiiit lol (excuse my fenech) It WAS the OnThink, HOWEVER: Every frame in the console looks like this: [link](http://img1.uploadscreenshot.com/images/orig/8/21420404786-orig.jpg)

Comment: Get rid of line 2 from the sample code (so it just says `local timers = {}`) - that initial entry was just an example of what the contents of the table would look like.

Comment: I see! Will try now: NICE! You are the best! Working, correct answer goes to you xP (would vote up but rep not high enough!) You deserve an invitation to the internet league of superheroes :p